# Setting up karma, chai, requirejs, chai-jquery

Tags: requirejs, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai, karma-mocha

I'm close to getting our tests to run with Karma but I'm missing the last step (I think), getting `chai-jquery` to behave, I've tried two different plugins https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-chai-jquery and https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jquery-chai with no success, even after following the specified order set in their various github issues or readme files.

This is my `tests-main.js` file

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
        allTestFiles.push(file);
    }
});

require.config({

    baseUrl: '/base',

    paths: {
        'chai':             'node_modules/chai/chai',
        'chai-jquery':      'node_modules/chai-jquery/chai-jquery',
        'jquery':           '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery',
        'underscore':       '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min',
        'sn/sn-underscore': 'static/scripts/sn/sn-underscore',
        'vendor/jquery-ui': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min'
    },

    deps: allTestFiles,

    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

This is my `karma.conf.js` (removed all non-crucial or default options)

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        // Can't use chai in here for whatever reason
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs'],
        files: [
            'static/scripts-test/test-main.js',
            {pattern: 'node_modules/chai/chai.js', included: true},
            {pattern: 'static/scripts-test/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'static/scripts/sn/**/*.js', included: false}
        ],
        exclude: [
            'static/scripts/global.js'
        ],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
    });
};
```

This is a "working" spec file, it correctly uses gets the references to `chai` and `jquery`, but loading `chai-jquery` fails every time.

```
define([
    'chai',
    'jquery',
    'static/scripts/sn/widgets/dismissable'
], function(chai, $) {
    chai.should();
    chai.expect();

    describe('Dismissable', function() {
        var $el = $('</p>'),
            closeBtnSel = '.js-dismissable-close-btn';

        beforeEach(function() {
            $('body').append('<div id="fixtures"></div>');
            $el.appendTo('#fixtures').dismissable({closeFn: 'hide'});
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            $el.remove();
        });

        it('should correctly create the HTML', function() {
            $(closeBtnSel).should.exist;
            $el.should.have.class('dismissable');
        });
    });
});
```

The error that I get is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$(closeBtnSel).should.exist')
```

This is my directory structure:

```
- static/
  - scripts/
  - scripts-test/
    - test-main.js
- node_modules/
- karma.conf.js
```

And finally, my `package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^2.3.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.1.10",
    "karma-requirejs": "*",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.18",
    "should": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
```

Some of the errors I usually get:

When changing the order of the frameworks in the `karma.conf`

```
    throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
                ^
    Error: No provider for "framework:chai"! (Resolving: framework:chai)
```

even after installing the plugin

Sometimes I'll get something like this:

```
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($) {
        return function (chai, utils) {
          return chaiJquery(chai, utils, $);
        };
      }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated here, I can't wrap my head around this.

EDIT: Small change based on recommendation from Louis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install the "should" API, you should do `chai.should()`, that is, *call* the function. The line `var should = chai.should` is not doing anything useful.

It was not initially clear to me whether your issue with `should` was causing a cascade of problems or if there was something else going on. I've taken a second look and found that there are indeed more problems.

#### RequireJS Loading from CDN + Karma

There seem to be a bug in Karma there. See [this issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-requirejs/issues/16), which is still open. There's also [that issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/421) which is closed but appears informative. So I've replaced the CDN with a local copy. Otherwise, I get:

```
ERROR: There is no timestamp for //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js!
```

#### Chai

One problem is that you have to decide whether you want to load `chai` with a `script` element or through RequireJS. The code in your question tries to do *both*, which can cause problems. I've decided to have it be loaded by RequireJS. This means that it should have `included: false`.

#### `chai-jquery`

Your test file is not loading `chai-jquery` and not asking `chai` to use it. So it is non-existent as far as your code is concerned. The intermittent loading problems you reported may be caused by code in other test files. The `require.config` call has `deps: allTestFiles`, but this does not specify any order. RequireJS is free to load the files in `allTestFiles` in whatever order it wants.

#### An Example

I took the code you posted in your question as the basis for an example. Obviously, I do not have all the code you have on your side.

Here is the new `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs'],
        files: [
            'static/scripts-test/test-main.js',
            {pattern: 'node_modules/chai/chai.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
             included: false},
            {pattern: 'node_modules/chai-jquery/chai-jquery.js',
             included: false},
            {pattern: 'static/scripts-test/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'static/scripts/sn/**/*.js', included: false}
        ],
        exclude: [
            'static/scripts/global.js'
        ],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
    });
};
```

The new `static/scripts-test/test-main.js` which loads jQuery locally:

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
        allTestFiles.push(file);
    }
});

require.config({

    baseUrl: '/base',

    paths: {
        'chai':             'node_modules/chai/chai',
        'chai-jquery':      'node_modules/chai-jquery/chai-jquery',
        'jquery':           'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        'underscore':       '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min',
        'sn/sn-underscore': 'static/scripts/sn/sn-underscore',
        'vendor/jquery-ui': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min'
    },

    deps: allTestFiles,

    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

A correct test file named `static/scripts-test/foo.spec.js`, note the use of `chai.use(chai_jquery)`:

```
define([
    'chai',
    'jquery',
    'chai-jquery',
], function(chai, $, chai_jquery) {
    chai.should();
    chai.use(chai_jquery);

    describe('example', function() {
        it('body should exist', function() {
            $(document.body).should.exist;
        });

        it('#blah should not exist', function() {
            $("#blah").should.not.exist;
        });
    });
});
```

The code above runs without problem:

```
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/tmp/t5/static/scripts/sn/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 43.0.2357 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket Za9vBp9shDedsIhcNn63 with id 48683492
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.005 secs / 0.002 secs)
```

I use Chrome as my browser but that's the only difference.

Comment: thanks, that kind of cleans up the should part, but the part I'm struggling the most is the `jquery-chai` part

Comment: That was it! When I initially setup my HTML test runner I had everything in script tags, so I never called `chai.use` before. I had seen the missing timestamps error before, but disregarded them since the tests ran fine without them.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you! I was going back and forth on this for 2 days and totally frustrated. Finally able to set it all up!